# Publish ASP 5 application to Azure in a custom environment

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-1.0

In my ASP.NET 5 (core, vNext) application I have:

- appsettings.test.json
- appsettings.development.json
- appsettings.staging.json
- appsettings.production.json
- appsetings.cloud.json

Each of these include different connection strings (for different environments).

**Problem**

When I publish my application to Azure, it automatically uses the `Production` environment.

I want to use the `Cloud` environment, when I publish to Azure.

**Note**

I am using the one month free trial of Azure, which wont allow me to create deployment slots (I need to upgrade).

**Question**

So, is there anyways I can publish to Azure  in my custom environment (`Cloud`) by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is there anyways I can publish to Azure in my custom environment (Cloud) by default?

**Yes.**

The easiest way is the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com). Go to MyWebApp > Settings > Application Settings > App settings. Set the `ASPNET_ENV` variable to `Cloud`.

[image: ASPNET_ENV App settings]

We can test this with a simple ASP.NET Core application.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json");

        builder.Build();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response
                .WriteAsync("Hello from " + env.EnvironmentName);
        });
    }
}
```

It works as expected.

[image: Hello from Cloud]

Comment: Thanks for helpful post, I am wondering, how does it "default" to production environment since there is no ASPNET_ENV:Production. Is it hardcoded somewhere to be production out of the box?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik The default value is "Production". Here is the relevant source code location https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/b6da89f54cff11474f17486cdc55c2f21f2bbd6b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostingEnvironment.cs#L10

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ASPNET_ENV` in your command line. Like `set ASPNET_ENV = cloud`, you can also change the environemnt in VS by right clicking on your project and selecting properties, then click debug.  In the Environment vars you can edit the Hosting Environment.  You can also look at [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1071) for more ways to change the environment.

Comment: Those are local techniques. How do they help with Azure?